# How to test my Dockerfile for my python project using GitHub actions?

Tags: python, docker, testing, github-actions

- Sometimes we make errors in writing the docker file. If there is an error in the Dockerfile, the docker build will fail.
- Sometimes we may forget to specify dependencies in our Dockerfile. Let's take an example.

Suppose, I have a python script that can take the screenshot of any web page (whose URL is supplied).

- Now, in my code I am using pyppeeteer(Headless chrome/chromium automation library (unofficial port of puppeteer)
- pyppeeteer uses chromium and chrome driver. These are already installed in my machine. So, running `pytest`  will pass in my local dev environment.
- I forget to specify the `RUN` commands in the dockerfile, that will install chromium and chrome driver. so running tests inside the container will fail. (although the `docker build` will succeed.)

I want to automate the task of building docker images and running tests in the container.

In the local machine, I can run `docker build -t myproj .` to build.

and for testing, I can run `docker run -it myproj pytest` (if i forget to add the `RUN` that installs chromium and chromedriver, then my pytest will fail inside container)

I hope I am able to explain my purpose.

Normally,in github actions,the python source code can be run on ubuntu, mac, windows etc.
Besides the different os, I also want to build and test my dockerfile.

Answer (score 14):

After a little more experimenting and research I found out that the solution to my problem is simple.

Inside the `.github/workflows` folder create a `docker-build-test.yml` file.

```yaml
 
name: Docker build and test

on:
  workflow_dispatch 
# you can trigger on anything you want

jobs:
  build:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - name: Build Docker image 
       run: docker build -t samplepy .
     - name: Run tests inside the container
       run: docker run samplepy poetry run pytest
```

Its very simple, because github's ubuntu-latest VMs already have docker installed and configured. You just run the `docker` command and **everything just works.**

And, I tested the above workflow with a dummy python project also.

[image: Screenshot from 2021-04-17 14-02-29]

Comment: feel free to post your answer, i am curious to know other way of doing this thing

Comment: what if your test needs some env variables? How would you do that?